# Magento 2 - How to generate coupon code?

Tags: magento2, coupon-codes

In Magento 2, How to generate coupon codes ? Please show me step by step, Thanks!

Comment: Did u try to google before posting here ????

Comment: Check this http://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/how-to-create-coupons-code-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process of generating coupon code in Magento 2 is almost similar to  Magento previous versions such as 1.9 etc 
You can generate it under

**Marketing -> Cart Price Rules -> Add New Rule**

For detailed description please follow these links given below

http://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/how-to-create-coupons-code-in-magento-2/

One more link for older Magento version such as

http://www.pixafy.com/blog/2013/08/how-to-create-coupon-codes-in-magento-beginners-tutorial-1/